# Apache Tapestry 5.4

Tags: apache, tapestry

I want to learn Tapestry, but I read in the documentation that version 5.4 is coming soon. It's now in beta version 22.

I also read that there will be a great difference between 5.3 and 5.4 on the level of Javascript implementation.

Can I start using the beta version or do you recommend to wait until the version 5.4 is released for production environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beta versions are quite stable (Tapestry code in general is quite stable). If you can accept a very small amount of risk (that there will be disruptive changes between now and the GA release) you will be vastly rewarded with what 5.4 has to offer over 5.3.